# How to make the node translation?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

The solarsystem case can make node rotate and I want to know how to animate an Object up and down？
This is the solarsystem case code:

```
Quaternion orientation1 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 0);
Quaternion orientation2 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 120);
Quaternion orientation3 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 240);
Quaternion orientation4 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 360);
ObjectAnimator orbitAnimation = new ObjectAnimator();
orbitAnimation.setObjectValues(orientation1, orientation2, orientation3, orientation4);
orbitAnimation.setPropertyName("localRotation");
orbitAnimation.setEvaluator(new QuaternionEvaluator());
orbitAnimation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
orbitAnimation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
orbitAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
orbitAnimation.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, It is the wrong consideration. Because [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator) can only animate subclass of [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) (like TextView, Button etc). But doesn't include [Node](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/Node). 
 According to Documentation,

> A Node represents a transformation within the scene graph's hierarchy.
>   It can contain a renderable for the rendering engine to render.

You need more research about [Node](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/Node)  to make rotate

Comment: I modify the problem, can you please revisit it?

Comment: There was no attribute for View "localRotation". Please change View.rotationY or rotationX

Answer (score 0):

I work in this code:

```
Vector3 vector1 = new Vector3(getRandom(), getRandom(), playNode.getLocalPosition().z);
    ObjectAnimator dropAnimation = new ObjectAnimator();
    dropAnimation.setObjectValues(vector1);
    dropAnimation.setPropertyName("localPosition");
    dropAnimation.setEvaluator(new Vector3Evaluator());
    dropAnimation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    dropAnimation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
    dropAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    dropAnimation.setAutoCancel(true);

    return dropAnimation;
```